# How to determine the "name" of a git remote, from its URL?

Tags: git, shell, version-control, grep, repository

Imagine a cloned repo with several remotes...

```
origin      https://github.com/mralexgray/HTTPKit (fetch)
origin      https://github.com/mralexgray/HTTPKit (push)
upstream    https://github.com/maintainer/HTTPKit (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/maintainer/HTTPKit (push)
someguy     https://github.com/joeFschmoe/HTTPKit (fetch)
someguy     https://github.com/joeFschmoe/HTTPKit (push)
```

I am wanting to automate "some operation" dealing with renaming remotes, etc.. and I KNOW the URL's, but not the NAMES. Instead of failing on a rename that already HAS an existing entry...

```
git remote rename origin upstream
fatal: remote upstream already exists.
```

How can I "grep" for the existing "name" of a checked out remote.. without resorting to well, *grepping*!?

```
git remote --localname https://github.com/joeFschmoe/HTTPKit
-> someguy
```

Comment: What's the issue with grepping?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo I'd have grep the match, then figure out which line, and then extract the name, blah blah blah.. lot's of error-prone steps.

Comment: @alexgray what do you mean? grep already gives you the line with the remote's name. just use the first word of the first line grep returns.

Comment: additionally, what is wrong with just using the URL in your command (all push/fetch commands also accept urls)?

Comment: @NevikRehnel there are config items keyed to the remote name

Comment: @jthill but those are not relevant for all operations. OP just mentions "some operation", which isn't great for getting help

Comment: Use awk.  It's built for stuff like this.  It won't take you two hours to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Since the name of the remotes is on the far left of the output, you can cut it very simply from the line that you grep (doesn't feel too error prone).

I use:

```
git remote -v | grep ":${ACCOUNT}/" | grep "(${TYPE})" | cut -f1
```

Where ACCOUNT is the account name (on GitHub), and TYPE is either "fetch" or "push"

Answer (score 0):

You can start by:

- renaming a remote ([`git remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote))

  ```
  git remote rename origin upstream
  fatal: remote upstream already exists.
  ```
- and if that fails (status `$? != 0`), set the url of the remote which already exists:

  ```
  git remote set-url upstream $(git config --get remote.origin.url)
  git remote set-url origin /another/url
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Given that we already have the new name for the remote URL. If it is of any help the following command doesn't fail if a remote name and url is already present.

`git remote set-url --add <name> <url>`

Remote Data:

```
Name1 URL1
Name2 URL2
```

Run:

```
git remote set-url --add Name3 URL1
git remote set-url --add Name1 URL1
```

New Remote Data:

```
Name1 URL1
Name2 URL2
Name3 URL1
```

Answer (score -2):

Ok, so the commenters shamed me into researching it, myself (ugh, *head AND awk*, lol)  I *don't now why* they don't JUST ANSWER instead of this peanut-gallery-nonsense... but..

```
git remote -v | grep $URL | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

seems to do the trick.  Thanks, guys! Not.

Comment: We’re not here to do your work. We can help you, but we don’t do your job.